# Retrieve the most recent row - pre- Oracle 12c

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

Please bear with me as I am new to all this.

My query is, I  have the following table and I am attempting to retrieve the most recent NOTE_PAD.NOTE_TEXT against the order.
Example of how the table looks like is below.

The data in the below table is obtained from joining two separate tables.
I  have used the following syntax for the join and retrieved only a specific order number for this example (867318) as there are many orders in the data base.

Not certain if I’ve made it clear enough, but if not let me know if there is any specific information needed and I will try my best to provide.
As mentioned please bear with me as I am totally new to this 

SQL Syntax:

```
SELECT ORDER_TYPE,
       ORDER_NUMBER,
       ORDER_LINE,
       NOTE_PAD.CREATED_DATE
  FROM ORDER_AWB INNER JOIN
       NOTE_PAD
       ON ( "ORDER_AWB"."NOTES" = "NOTE_PAD"."NOTES" )
WHERE ( "ORDER_AWB"."ORDER_NUMBER" = '867318' )
```

Example of table result when above syntax is used:
[image]

Comment: Which brand of SQL are you using? MySQL, MS SQL Server, Oracle, etc.?

Comment: And you want just the second row of those two?

Comment: to be honest I've got no clue on the brand of SQL. The database is an MIS (Maintenance Information Software system) and the software has a module that can be used to create customized reports based on the users needs. Yes I need to only extract the second row or the most recently entered notes text against the order.

Comment: What program are you using ?

Comment: The MIS program is called TRAX (used in the airline/aviation industry)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an Oracle DB pre 12c this should work

```
SELECT * FROM
  (
  SELECT ORDER_TYPE,
         ORDER_NUMBER,
         ORDER_LINE,
         NOTE_PAD.CREATED_DATE
  FROM ORDER_AWB INNER JOIN
         NOTE_PAD ON ( "ORDER_AWB"."NOTES" = "NOTE_PAD"."NOTES" )
  WHERE ( "ORDER_AWB"."ORDER_NUMBER" = '867318' )
  ORDER BY NOTE_PAD.CREATED_DATE DESC
  )
WHERE ROWNUM <= 1
```

Comment: Brilliant :) thanks a LOT! Yes i removed the ; at the end.

Comment: Glad to help. Remember to hit "Accept Answer" so I don't have ta come send my boys over :)

Answer (score 0):

From having a quick google it looks like the TRAX software it's using Oracle. If it's version 12c (12.1) or later and you're only looking to query one order at a time then putting this onto the **end** of your query should work

```
ORDER BY NOTE_PAD.CREATED_DATE DESC
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: Tried it, but no luck :( I get an ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended. If I'm doing something incorrectly please correct me.             SELECT ORDER_TYPE,
       ORDER_NUMBER,
       ORDER_LINE,
       NOTE_PAD.CREATED_DATE
  FROM ORDER_AWB INNER JOIN
       NOTE_PAD
       ON ( "ORDER_AWB"."NOTES" = "NOTE_PAD"."NOTES" )
WHERE ( "ORDER_AWB"."ORDER_NUMBER" = '867318' )
ORDER BY NOTE_PAD.CREATED_DATE DESC
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY

Comment: What's the error message or does it just not return the right data?

Comment: Make sure you have a `;` on the end

Comment: And you don't have a `;` earlier in your script like where it was previously ended?

Comment: Aslo make sure that the type of column "created_date" is realy DATE type. If it's varchar() it won't work correctly. If it's varchar() covert it in query with TO_DATE() function

Comment: Answering Adamantish: No there is no need for a ; it works without it with my previous script. If I input a ; I get an error ORA-00911: invalid character

Comment: Ah, the DB adapter is probably doing that bit for you.

Comment: Also if you finally get it returning one row but it's the wrong one then it's probably because of what @Nomeaning25 suggested.