# What is the most accurate/efficient method to retrieve recently entered text without changing ROWNUM?

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group, rownum

Please bear with me as I am new to all this. I was given an answer to a previous query which was really helpful.
Now I am attempting to complete another step of the project.

My query is, I  have a table and I am attempting to retrieve the most recent notes entered against a particular line of the order.
Example of how the tables looks like are below.

The data in the below table is obtained from joining two separate tables.

I used the following Syntax, and am able to obtain the most recent notes entered against an example order (867318)
However now, in a situation where the order has multiple lines (ORDER_LINE) how can I retrieve the most recent NOTE_PAD.TEXT entered against the ORDER_LINE ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**SQL Brand:** Oracle DB pre 12c  
**Date format:** Is in real date/time
**Issue:** Most accurate/efficient method to retrieve the most recently entered NOTE_PAD.TEXT without changing ROWNUM each time depending on the ORDER_NUMBER

SQL Syntax:

```
 SELECT *
  FROM ( SELECT ORDER_TYPE,
                ORDER_NUMBER,
                ORDER_LINE,
                NOTE_PAD.CREATED_DATE,
                NOTE_PAD.TEXT
                           FROM ORDER_AWB INNER JOIN NOTE_PAD ON ( "ORDER_AWB"."NOTES" = "NOTE_PAD"."NOTES" )
          WHERE ( "ORDER_AWB"."ORDER_NUMBER" = '867318' )
          ORDER BY NOTE_PAD.CREATED_DATE DESC )
WHERE ROWNUM <= 1
```

**Example of table result when above syntax is used:** [image]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5WKT.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/e02YS.png  
 So basically this is the how the entire code looks like in the DB:  
 I need to retrieve the notes against the particular type of order and it’s status.  
 Hence  
ORDER_TYPE = ‘RO’  
ORDER_STATUS = ‘OPEN’  
[image: code]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve the most recent NOTE\_TEXT against orders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34767708/retrieve-the-most-recent-note-text-against-orders)

Comment: It is, and works fine if the it's a single order_number. But now I am attempting to retrieve it for multiple orders

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle multiple orders at the same time, then use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT ORDER_TYPE, np, ORDER_LINE,
             np.CREATED_DATE, NOTE_PAD.TEXT,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY o.ORDER_NUMBER
                                ORDER BY NP.CREATED_DATE DESC
                               ) as seqnum
      FROM ORDER_AWB o INNER JOIN
           NOTE_PAD np
           ON o."NOTES" = np."NOTES" 
     ) o
WHERE SEQNUM = 1;
```

Comment: What is your Oracle Version? SELECT * FROM V$VERSION if you don't know.

Comment: tks for the pointer, I ran the script you gave me and this is what came up  <br/> Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production  <br/> PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production

Comment: @joshmc . . . Oracle 11g supports `partition by`.  Now that I've added a comma at the end of the previous row, it might work.

Comment: @joshmc . . . Your code is missing a comma just before the `row_number()`.

Comment: These are the results that are spit out on these combinations, see link. http://i.stack.imgur.com/sJsIY.png

Comment: @joshmc . . . `seqnum = 1` would seem to answer your question:  "I have a table and I am attempting to retrieve the most recent notes entered against a particular line of the order. "  If you want two rows then use `<= 2`, for instance.